# How can I specify letter spacing or kerning, in a WPF TextBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, kerning

I'd like to modify the spacing between characters in a WPF TextBox.
Something like the `letter-spacing: 5px` thing that is available in CSS.
I think it is possible in XAML; what's the simplest way?

I found the "[Introduction to the GlyphRun Object and Glyphs Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748985.aspx)" document, and found it to be exceedingly unhelpful.

This is a code example from that page:

```
<!-- "Hello World!" with explicit character widths for proportional font -->
<Glyphs 
   FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ARIAL.TTF"
   FontRenderingEmSize = "36"
   UnicodeString       = "Hello World!"
   Indices             = ",80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80;,80"
   Fill                = "Maroon"
   OriginX             = "50"
   OriginY             = "225"
/>
```

The same documentation page gives this "explanation" for what the `Indices` property does:

[image]

I have no idea what any of that means. I'm also not sure that Indices is the right thing - the comment in the code speaks of "character widths" which I don't care about. I want to adjust the width *between* characters.

Also, there is no example for how to apply a `Glyphs` element to a TextBox.  When I tried it, my WPF test app just crashed.

---

What I want to do is slightly increase the empty space that appears between drawn characters within a WPF TextBox.  The text will vary in length and content.  Do I have to modify the `Indicies` property every time there is a new character? Is there a way to say "make it 20% more space than usual, for every character".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I tried Glyphs and FontStretch and couldn't easily get the result I was looking for.  I was able to come up with an approach that works for my purposes.  Maybe it will work for others, as well.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeString}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                       Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I can bind to any string and don't need to do any character width detection to set the spacing properly.  The right margin is the space *between* the letters.

Example:

[image: Kerning]

Comment: This is a nice solution (I up voted it), but this can definitely cause performance problems. We use this solution in some places, but we wanted to use it in an `ItemsControl` with a few hundred items and it was adding multiple seconds to the rendering time. We went back to a regular `TextBlock` in those scenarios. So just be aware/careful!

Comment: This also will break the ability to trim or wrap text.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to have letter spacing with [TextBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock?view=net-5.0) class as it supports [TranslateTransforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.translatetransform?view=net-5.0). By replacing a default `PropertyChangedCallback` on the `TextBlock.TextProperty` with a custom one, we can apply `TranslateTransform` to each letter in the `TextBlock`.

Here is a complete step-by-step coding I did:

First, we create a custom class and inherit from `TextBlock` like so:

```cs
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyApp
{
    class SpacedLetterTextBlock : TextBlock
    {
        public SpacedLetterTextBlock() : base()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in XAML, we change the TextBlock to our custom class (more information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-and-custom-classes-for-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0)):

```xaml
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:MyApp">
   <Grid>
       <app:SpacedLetterTextBlock>
           Some Text
       </app:SpacedLetterTextBlock>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Finally, before the `InitializeComponent()` method in the `.cs` code-behind file, add the `OverrideMetadata` method like so:

```cs
// This line of code adds our own callback method to handle any changes in the Text
//   property of the TextBlock
SpacedLetterTextBlock.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(SpacedLetterTextBlock),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)
    )
);
```

... and apply `TranslateTransform` to each letter each time `TextProperty` changes:

```cs
private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SpaceLettersOut(d);
}

// This method takes our custom text block and 'moves' each letter left or right by 
//  applying a TranslateTransform
private static void SpaceLettersOut(DependencyObject d)
{
    SpacedLetterTextBlock thisBlock = (SpacedLetterTextBlock)d;
            
    for (int i = 1; i <= thisBlock.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        // TranslateTransform supports doubles and negative numbers, so you can have
        //  whatever spacing you need - do see 'Notes' section in the answer for
        //  some limitations.
        TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform(2, 0);
        TextEffect effect = new TextEffect();
        effect.Transform = transform;
        effect.PositionStart = i;
        effect.PositionCount = thisBlock.Text.Length;

        thisBlock.TextEffects.Add(effect);
        if (effect.CanFreeze)
        {
            effect.Freeze();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTES**:

First, I am a complete novice in WPF and C#, so my answer might not be the cleanest solution available. If you have any comments on how to improve this answer, it will be greatly appreciated!

Second, I haven't tested this solution with a large number of `TextBlock` elements, and there (probably) is a huge performance penalty as `TranslateTransform` is applied to each individual letter in a `TextBlock.Text`.

Finally, the text of the `TextBlock` goes out of bounds with any positive `X` value for `TranslateTransform`. I think that you can re-calculate the width of the `TextBlock` and only then place it programmatically (?)

Answer (score 1):

is [FontStretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontstretch.aspx) an option for you?

Otherwise you might want to look into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx) there is an image, showing what advance width means. Though I have not done this before and don't know if this works increasing right and left side bearings might be what you want!

Answer (score -4):

For what its worth . . .

If you have the option to switch your implementation to RichTextBox, this might be easier than the work-around you found Sept 2013.  I just tried it for my own needs and it works for what I need.  I do not see a way with RichTextBox to control kerning of individual spaces like typesetters do.  But TextBox was eating additional spaces (consolidating multiple adjacent spaces to a single space) like HTML.  I needed for the spaces to display the same amount of spacing as is in my text String, and RichTextBox does this.

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextBox"></RichTextBox>
```

I'm no expert, but it seems you can't specify the text content in XAML.  I had to specify it in a code-behind event:

```
this.MyRichTextBox.AppendText("V A R I E D      S P A C E S");
```