# How to set Kerning Character Spacing in WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I cannot find how to set horizontal character spacing in a RichTextBox.

`Hello, World!
H e l l o ,  W o r l d !`

---

I can only set vertical Line Height using C#.

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.LineHeight = 50;

rtb1.Document = new FlowDocument(p);

p.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello, World!"));
```

And outer margin with XAML.

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtb1" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Height="600"
       Width="300" 
       Margin="188,61,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <RichTextBox.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
             <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50"/>
         </Style>
     </RichTextBox.Resources>
 </RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common options you have are:

- [Control.FontStretch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontstretch.aspx)
- [Glyphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/introduction-to-the-glyphrun-object-and-glyphs-element)

but here on SO a user found a nice (although potentially performance intensive) alternative to both (read the accepted answer):

[How can I specify letter spacing or kerning, in a WPF TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843562/how-can-i-specify-letter-spacing-or-kerning-in-a-wpf-textbox)

Comment: How can it be applied to RichTextBox?